# how to split and upload a theme on wordpress?

Tags: plugins, themes, uploads, limit

I have created an account on googiehost and unfortunately the hosting company has limited the file upload size to 2MB. Since the hosting is free on googiehost  the hosting provider may not agree to increase the file upload size for just my account. And now i have this Divi theme which is 8 MB in size and i am unable to upload it due to the limit. So i thought off splitting the Divi.zip file into 4 X 2MB chunks which later makes up 8MB(The theme) and then give to any plugin so that it takes all the chunks and extract them to the path where the theme is actually supposed to be installed. So my question is there any plugin as such which does what i want.

Comment: There are thousands of hosting providers without such a limit. Why aren't you using one of them?

Comment: @fuxia Can you Please suggest me someone? And i am using googiehost because it's free and also providing 99.99 percent uptime and also unlimited bandwith.

Comment: I'd ask googiehost support if they can upload the 8MB file for you as a one-off. That's going to be easier than trying to work around the restriction.

Comment: If you have an FTP access to your WP folder, you can upload your theme unpacked, file-by-file.